# Matplotlib legend not working for ternary scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter, ternary

I am trying to plot a legend for my ternary scatterplot, where I have colored the points based on if they are categorized as "Iv", "SK" or "St", but for some reason, only the first point "Iv" shows up in the legend. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
t = df.loc['591686B' : '591697C2','C']
l = df.loc['591686B' : '591697C2', 'O']
r = df.loc['591686B' : '591697C2','P']

colors = {'Iv':'red', 'SK':'green', 'St':'blue'}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = plt.subplot(projection='ternary')
plot = ax.scatter(t, l, r, s=50, c=df['Locality'].map(colors), alpha=0.8, edgecolors='black', marker="o", linewidths=0.3) 

plt.grid()
ax.legend(('Iv','SK', 'St'))
ax.set_tlabel('C')
ax.set_llabel('O')
ax.set_rlabel('P')
plt.show()
```

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really understand what to do!

Comment: Well, as explained in the linked documents, you need to call scatter 3 times, once for each color. `for lbl in ('Iv','SK', 'St'): filter = (df['Locality'] == lbl); ax.scatter(t[filter], l[filter], r[filter], s=50, c=colors[lbl], label=lbl, ... )`